# How to use Fabric.io with a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, fabric.io

I have installed the Fabric SDK into my Xamarin project, but after testing a crash as well as multiple "messages" the Fabric.io site is not reporting any activity.

This is the information that is reported from the debug logs

> 2018-02-27 16:32:10.518 [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121) 2018-02-27
>   16:32:10.617 [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id
>   '678047d5dc264b67b63a792798592bc5' for submission 2018-02-27
>   16:32:11.015 [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report 2018-02-27
>   16:32:11.015 [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.myapp.bundleID/v3/prepared/hash.multipartmime
>   2018-02-27 16:32:11.016 [Crashlytics:Crash:Client] A task currently
>   exists for this upload, skipping 2018-02-27 16:32:11.066 [Fabric]
>   settings downloaded successfully 2018-02-27 16:32:11.066 [Fabric]
>   Settings are available for consumption 2018-02-27 16:32:11.251
>   [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/hash/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.myapp.bundleID/v3/prepared/hash.multipartmime
>   2018-02-27 16:32:11.252 [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission
>   successful 2018-02-27 16:32:12.723 [Crashlytics:Crash] Warning:
>   NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'xamarin_get_block_descriptor' in
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/hash/AppName.iOS.app/AppName.iOS'

And this is the code Initialize the crashlytics/fabric app (it is the first thing called in the 'finished launching' method

> Crashlytics.Instance.Initialize(); Fabric.Instance.Initialize();
>   Fabric.Instance.Debug = true; Crashlytics.Instance.Log("Hello world");
>   <-- attempting to get something to show up on the website.

I have used Charles Proxy and I can see data being transferred back and forth, but the fabric.io website is not recording it. How do I get data to show up in fabric?